# Can you output data in C++ without using any includes?

Tags: c++

This is a thought experiment.
This question is intentionally trying to do something easy in a difficult way. I am aware of the many ways to do this using iostream, std.h, etc. Please do not suggest answers that circumvent the challenge.

Using C++,
Only using main() without any header files included, is it possible to write a program that creates a variable of any type, and outputs the value of the variable in any way, such as printing it in console, saving it to a file, anything like that?

The goal is to have a .main file that looks like:

```
int main(){
    Some code;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using C's printf but that requires a header.
The best I could come up with is saving the value to a specific space in memory then using another program to read that block. But that is somewhat circumventing the goal of outputting only from main.

This may be impossible.

Comment: If you're fine with a non portable solution, you can try and do this using inline assembly.

Comment: I believe old visual studio compilers didn't require you to include `iostream` for `cout`, but that was a long time ago.

Comment: Just copy-paste the declarations from the headers you need into your own code?

Comment: You can copy-paste just the declaration of `printf`, even put it inside of `main`.

Comment: Other possibilities: make a syscall using inline assembly. Or make a type named with the message you want to print, throw an uncaught exception of that type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have no code outside of `main`, in C you could do this:

```
int main()
{
    int puts(const char *);
    puts("Sup!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Or the same thing with `printf`, or any other C standard library function.

It wouldn't work in C++ though, since in C++ the `puts` declaration needs `extern "C"` to disable name mangling, which can only be used outside of functions.

There's a trick that lets you do it in C++:

```
int main()
{
    extern int puts;
    ((int(*)(const char *))&puts)("Sup!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Variable names are not mangled, so by tricking the compiler into thinking that `puts` is a variable rather than a function, you can get rid of the mangling without `extern C`.

Comment: @Iforgetmyaccoundalot Nothing is impossible, the foot-shooting possibilities are endless. :P

Answer (score 3):

Technically, this satisfies your constraints:

```
int main() {
  return 123;
}
```

Most OSs allow you to check a program's return code. So this communicates one number to the outside world. The available range of values may differ with the OS.

Comment: This is technically correct. I now wonder if there is a more flashy way to output but this does work and meets all the requirements. It outputs a value created inside the program to the system only using main.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "only main", but `extern "C"` cannot go into a block. So, if you can live with that line outside the main function, here's the code you asked for:

```
extern "C" int printf(const char *fmt, ...);

int main() {
    printf("Hello %s\n", "world");
    return 0;
}
```

Proof: https://godbolt.org/z/41WhGYc79

Comment: Thanks, that's a good answer but the goal is only to have a clean main. It may be impossible though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I haven't understood correctly, but if you want to avoid the includes/libraries then the short answer is no. A C++ header (apart from templates) is just a declaration of a possible link-time function availability and you will always need them.

Almost anything meaningful you can do with C++ (as in any programming language, even assembly) requires a call to the underlying OS and this requires a header and a library link.

Even something as simple as a char output requires thousands of lines to communicate with a device driver to output to screen.

Even if you don't include anything, the compiler will inject code (CRT) that calls the OS by using a library no matter what. Even a simple main() requires lots of calls to the OS, for actually there is no "main" entry point in the executable.

Answer (score 0):

That does not exactly answer your question, but if you were doing this in C rather than C++, then for most compilers that would be a valid program (without any includes):

```
int main()
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Although it generates a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Combining two of the answers above I was able to use printf by replacing the parts of

```
extern int puts;
((int(*)(const char *))&puts)("Sup!\n");
```

With parts that would allow printf:

```
extern int printf;
((int(*)(const char *fmt, ...))&printf)("%d\n", 10);
```

So the full code would be:

```
int main(){
  int num = 10;
  extern int printf;
  ((int(*)(const char *fmt, ...))&printf)("%d\n", num);
  return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps, this is a combination of two responses not my own.